# Getting access to full json from an object validator

Tags: validation, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My web API expose following method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyPostMethod([FromBody]Company company)
{
   .......
}
```

The Company class look as follows

```
public class Company
    {
        public Guid CompanyGuid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }


[EmployeeValidation]
public class Employee
    {
        public Guid EmployeeGuid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see that Employee class is decorated with a validation attributes that is implemented as follows.

```
public class EmployeeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var logger = (ILogger<EmployeeValidationAttribute>)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ILogger<EmployeeValidationAttribute>));
            List<Employee> Employees = (List<Employee>)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            foreach (Employee Employee in Employees)
            {
                if (Employee.EmployeeGuid == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Invalid Employee Guid");
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Let's say when something goes wrong with the validation of the Employee object, I want to log the whole JSON input to MyPostMethod method. However within the validator, I only have access to the **Employee** object. Is there anyway I can get access to JSON input for the **Company** within validator for **Employee** object?

Answer (score 1):

The validationContext isn't going to know anything about the instance of Company.

You'll need to build a company validation attribute instead of just an employee one.

```
[CompanyValidation]
public class Company
{
    public String CompanyGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var logger = (ILogger<CompanyValidationAttribute>)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ILogger<CompanyValidationAttribute>));
        var company = (Company)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        // don't forget to check for null
        foreach (Employee Employee in company.Employees)
        {
            if (Employee.EmployeeGuid == Guid.Empty)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Invalid Employee Guid");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Another approach**

Here, the `value` parameter is just the single property in question but the `validationContext.ObjectInstance` becomes the container object, i.e. company.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public object Post([FromBody]Company company)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //log here
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class Company
{
    [GuidValidation]
    public Guid CompanyGuid { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [GuidValidation]
    public Guid EmployeeGuid { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class GuidValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null && validationContext.ObjectInstance != null)
        {
            var model = (Guid)value;

            if (model == Guid.Empty)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Guid cannot be empty.");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess point of my question is to know if its possible to get within a validator, I can get access to full JSON object. I understand that I can create a validator for the root object and validate all contained object there (like you suggested for validator for company) but that's what not I am trying to achieve. Also when a validator attributes report a validation error, request doesn't seem to make to the Post method.

Comment: @Jimcrown ok, I see... I didn't find that a class level validation attribute give you its container object, but a property level validation attribute would, not sure why... If the post is not binding to your Action's argument, then you'll have to review the naming conventions for asp.net mvc model binding capabilities.